# Error: Syntax error in DATA statement at (1)

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'm newbie in fortran

I'm try to compile one mathematical model as module and can't compile that by gfortran.

```
DATA HEADER/' YEAR MMDD UThr LThr XHI  SSN  COV  Kpm    L  ',
     &            '  Glati Glong Mlati Mlong MoDip  hmF2  foF2',
     &            '    NmF2   Nes       QF     MLT   ECbot  ECtop',
     &            '   ECpl   TEC    TAU  h05b  h05t   Hsc '/
```

How to fix it?

Comment: What is the **exact and full** code you are compiling? See [mcve]. In which column are those `&`s? What is the file extension? Is it .f or .f90?

Comment: The code compiles fine when I move the first line to the appropriate column and add some necessary boilerplate... You  must show the exact [mcve].

Comment: Although I already gave an answer, I still have a question. Is your code free or fixed source. (i.e. are there always 6 spaces before most lines or not?)

Answer (score 0):

You are encountering the horror of statement continuation (multiline statements) between free source form versus fixed source form. Why the horror? It is one of the very few cases why fixed source form cannot always be compiled as free source form:

> **Free form statement continuation:**
>   The character `&` is used to indicate that the statement is continued on the next line that is not a comment line. When used for continuation, the `&` is not part of the statement. If a noncharacter context is to be continued, an `&` shall be the last nonblank character on the line, or the last nonblank character before an `!`.

In short:

```
a = some + statement &
    that - needs * continuation
b = some / other * statement & ! that has a comment
    and - needs ** continuation
```

> **Fixed form statement continuation:** Except within commentary, character position **6** is used to indicate continuation. If character position 6 contains a blank or zero, the line is the initial line of a new statement, which begins in character position 7. If character position 6 contains any character other
>   than blank or zero, **character positions 7–72 of the line constitute a continuation of the preceding non-comment line.**

In short:

```
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012 < column_nr
      a = some + statement
     &    that - needs * continuation
      b = some / other * statement &
C that has a comment
     *    and - needs ** continuation
```

So the problem the OP seems to have is that he used Fixed form statement continuation in a free source form.

See the [Fortran Standard](https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-007.pdf) for more details.